# Boot2Docker starting Ubuntu image

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to get the latest Ubuntu image going om my Windows 7/Boot2Docker machine but when i try to start the image i get an error message.

```
exec: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Full errormessage:

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
exec: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash: no such file or directory
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 100e77a5ac95f8fb8dc55e6382e7a8cd6f946ec807e90d9efdb6fc905a046569: [8] System error: exec: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash": stat C:/P
rogram Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Any clue on how to work around this? Another image like the default Jenkins one works ok!

The Ubuntu image is pulled correctly

Running Ubuntu image after SSH:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run ubuntu
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that somehow your `$PATH` (within the boot2docker session) includes "`C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/`" *before* `/bin`.

Check the `$PATH` you have when running `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest`.

The fact that you manage to run the image in a `boot2docker ssh` session, but `docker ps` displays nothing seems expected.

Only a `docker run --rm -it ubuntu` would display a shell.
A simplt `docker run` would exit the shell immadiatly (non-interactive run), and the container would be in status '`Exited`' (see `docker ps -a` output)

Comment: When executing the command "docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest" and in the shell i get after that.. i execute $PATH.. The result = bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: @Marco so you do get to start the image and access the shell! Where is the error you mentioned initially?

Comment: When i start the "Boot2Docker Console" and after starting execute the command "docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash" i get the mentioned error. I updated the question with the full error.

Comment: I guess i am starting the image incorrect.. When i do start the image with using "docker run ubuntu:latest" i see no images when using docker ps

Comment: @Marco you need to do a `boot2docker start` followed by a `boot2docker ssh` (as, for instance, in https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/b2d.bat). Then in the ssh session, you won't have any issue.

Comment: @Marco I have edited the answer to explain why a `docker run` exits immediately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, before you create a container, you have to run "Boot2Docker Start" to start docker virtual machine then start your container inside docker VM. follow up the instructions in this link https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

Second, I think that it is preferred to install docker over linux machine not windows, you will get all capabilities of docker.

Best Regards,

Ahmed

Comment: No, I am using boot2docker 1.6 on Windows, and I have *all* the capabilities of docker (1.6)